# Canvas not loading on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

What is wrong with this function?

```
window.LoadImage = function(el, canvasId){
            var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var dialogCanvas = document.getElementsByClassName('dialogCanvas');
            var dialogContext = dialogCanvas[0].getContext("2d");
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event){
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function(){
                    var w = 545;
                    var imgW = img.width;
                    var imgH = img.height;
                    var dialogW = dialogCanvas[0].width;
                    var dialogH = dialogCanvas[0].height;

                    h = (imgH / imgW) * w;
                    dialogH = (imgH / imgW) * dialogW;  

                    context.clearRect(0, 0, w, imgH);
                    dialogContext.clearRect(0,0, dialogW, 250);
                    canvas.width = w;
                    canvas. height = h;
                    context.drawImage(img,0,0,w,h);
                    dialogContext.drawImage(img,0,0,dialogW, dialogH);

                }
            img.src = event.target.result;

            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); 
        }
```

I am trying to draw 2 different canvas with this function. Neither work on Firefox. And the damn thing works on Chrome and IE.

The "dialogCanvas" is a preview which is inside a jquery modal box and the other, reached using the "canvasId" parameter, has it's `display = "none"`, in the page.

I'm not getting any errors on firefox. Actually, I can't even debug it.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
jsfiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/cgEv8/

Comment: What do you mean, you can't debug it?  What happens when you try?

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle.net and/or add the code you are using to call this function.

Comment: @Pointy It's not that I can't debug it. It's just that it isn't stopping where I assumed to be the issue trigger.

Comment: @qw3n I'll try to recreate it in a bit.

Comment: Well the weird thing is that Firefox didn't throw an exception at that line ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out the event is undefined. In Firefox I get this error on the fiddle:

> ReferenceError: event is not defined. Try to handle event

You should rather handle the event using:

```
$('#t1-1-img-header').on('change', LoadImage);
```

Then in you handler you can use

```
function LoadImage(event) {

    var el = this;  /// this will be the calling element
    ...
}
```

(and of course you need to remove the onchange attribute in the element itself).

For the canvas ID you need to either pass it in directly or use some other means to store it so it is available to the callback scope.

**[Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/cgEv8/1/)**

Comment: Very nice, sir. Thanks for your help. Also, thanks for the others that helped leading to this answer. I did not picture that workaround before :D

Comment: @VicWolk no problem! We are here to help :)

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
```

refers to "event".  Where's that?  In some browsers it's a global object, but not in Firefox.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's not giving me anything on firefox. I simply put it there and it worked on Chrome and then on IE. What should be done to make it work on ff?